# Not able to use interstitialAd.setAdUnitId() method?

Tags: java, android, admob, google-ads-api

Although I have implemented `com.google.android.gms.ads:20.0.0` in my project, still I am not able to use `interstitialAd.setAdUnitId()`, `loadAd`.  
Here is what I have:

```
import androidx.multidex.BuildConfig;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.Adlistener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.IntersitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.intersitital.IntersisitalAd;
```

Here is where I'm trying to use the method:

```
public void interstitalLoadAd(Context context){
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(context);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(BuildConfig.DEBUG ?
        TEST_INTERSTITIAL_AD_UNIT_ID :
        INTERSTITIAL_AD_UNIT_ID);
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(this);
}

public void showAd(){
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()){
        mInterstitialAd.show(); 
}
```

[image: import of Ads class]

[image: Errors]

Comment: Did u try   "Invalid cache/Restart" ? . I have faced similar kind of problem. "Invalidate cache/Restart" worked for me.

Comment: Yes, many times even cleaned my build but that not working.